# How to reproduce a field with disable checkbox with Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects

I'd like to reproduce the field that can be disabled with a checkbox with Visualforce.

[image]

Shortly:

- A field should have label on the left side
- There should be a red bar indicating requirement for both the field and checkbox
- The field should be disabled/enabled on checkbox tick

I managed to solve first and get close to the second requirement with:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Name" for="opp"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="opp">
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Name}" required="true" />             
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!someMapping}" id="nooppti" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Do not create a new opportunity upon conversion." for="nooppti" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is a custom VF-page, I would use *javascript to invoke the disable/enable action* - probably with *jquery*

The other items you list are really just "stylist" items, for example, you can inherit some of the classes to recreate the "required" (red-line) style from VF-CSS that is available on each page.

```
<apex:page>

<script type="text/javascript">
//note I'm using jQuery 'ends-with' style selector to find the VF elements on the page with jQuery
function disableEnableField(){
   if($('[id=$"enabledisablecheckbox"]').is(':checked')){ 
      $('[id$="mytextinput"]').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
      $('[id$="mytextinput"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
      // add any other stylistic attributes to make it appear disabled
   }
}
</script>

<apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- using the requiredInput class on the output panel to get the red line -->
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
    <apex:inputField id="mytextinput" value="{!someObjectField}"/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox id="enabledisablecheckbox"onClick="disableEnableField();" />
</apex:outputPanel>
&nbsp; <!-- might need a second item here for VF tag pageBlockSectionItem -->
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock> 


</apex:page>
```

Comment: That will solve the javascript requirement, but it doesn't look like it's solving the visual requirement. I've updated my question to show how close I am visually.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your example, you need a "helper object" that's a boolean. When "true", the the new opportunity is created (the default value) and when "false" the new opportunity doesn't get created (the value when you click the checkbox).

You'll probably need to invert the logic for the checkbox's return values as I believe the default OnCheck value = "true". Conversely, you could reverse the meaning of the helper Object's values. Hope this is clearer than mud. :)

Comment: BTW, I've utilized this trick in combination with a trigger which is how you may need to implement it as well.